# Cordova camera on IOS 11 crashes

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-camera

I'm working on an IOS application made with Ionic and Cordova. I read that to access the camera it must be set the permission, so I modified the Info.plist file and added the following key:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Aggiungere immagini agli articoli</string>
<key>NSPhotolibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Aggiungere immagini agli articoli</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Aggiungere immagini agli articoli</string>
```

But when I run the app and select the button that open phone's camera, the camera open and the dialog window ask for permission, but the app suddenly crashes. 
I don't understand why? I should add something else in my controller code to wait on user permissions?
Thanks in advance

This is my config.xml file

```
<platform name="ios">
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
        <string>Aggiungere immagini agli articoli</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotolibraryAddUsageDescription">
        <string>Aggiungere immagini agli articoli</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
        <string>Aggiungere immagini agli articoli</string>
    </edit-config>
```

Comment: did you find any solution?